# AngularJS, issue on form validation

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, formvalidation-plugin

I have a form where the user needs to enter 2 times his email.
I found on the internet (but not able to find the link anymore) some angular code doing what I wanted.
The only issue is when the 2 emails are the same, one input still got the class

> .ng-invalid.ng-dirty

So I can't submit the form.

My code is the following:

css:

```
.ng-invalid.ng-dirty{
    border-color: #FA787E;
}

.ng-valid.ng-dirty{
    border-color: #78FA89;
}
```

html:

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
      <form name="formTemplate" novalidate>
        <input id="email1" type="email" ng-model="currentForm.email1" name="email1" required>
        <span ng-show="formTemplate.email1.$error.required && formTemplate.email1.$dirty">required</span>
        <span ng-show="!formTemplate.email1.$error.required && formTemplate.email1.$error.email1 && formTemplate.email1.$dirty">invalid email</span>  
        <input id="email2" type="email" name="email2" ng-model="currentForm.email2" same-email required>
        <span ng-show="formTemplate.email2.$error.required && formTemplate.email2.$dirty">Please confirm your email.</span>
        <span ng-show="!formTemplate.email2.$error.required && formTemplate.email2.$error.noMatch && formTemplate.email1.$dirty">Emails do not match.</span>
      </form>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['UserValidation']);

angular.module('UserValidation', []).directive('sameEmail', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, $scope) {
                var noMatch = viewValue != scope.formTemplate.email1.$viewValue;
                ctrl.$setValidity('noMatch', !noMatch)
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Here a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/pq6fw04v/

Comment: I think u are already validating.Thats way it show message email do not match

Answer (score 0):

Im **update** your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/pq6fw04v/). You don't return value from `ctrl.$parsers.unshift`.

```
ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, $scope) {
            var noMatch = viewValue != scope.formTemplate.email1.$viewValue;
            ctrl.$setValidity('noMatch', !noMatch);
            return noMatch;
        })
```

**Updated jsfiddle**

Comment: thanks for your help, but now it doesn't check if the 2 emails are the same

Comment: It's check. Please, check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/1hfxhgsk/1/)